# How to use XPath 3.1 in Saxon?

Tags: xpath, command-line, configuration, saxon, xpath-3.1

I am currently using XPath 3.1 syntax but for some reason Saxon outputs the error:

`To use XPath 3.1 syntax, you must configure the XPath parser to handle it`.

How do I do this?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: An update: the XSLT 3.0 Recommendation and Saxon 9.8 were released on the same day, 8 June 2017, and Saxon 9.8 supports XPath 3.1 unconditionally (in all editions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the s9api API, use `XPathCompiler.setLanguageVersion("3.1")`.

If you're using JAXP, that's probably a bad idea because the JAXP XPath API can't handle the richness of XPath 3.1 data types; but if you must, cast the XPath object to net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator; then call getStaticContext().setXPathLanguageLevel().

In Saxon 9.7 the default XPath language level supported is 3.0, because that's the latest W3C spec that has reached Recommendation status.

**UPDATE**

In Saxon 9.8, XPath 3.1 is the default.

Comment: @Michael. Are you sure? The docs say: "From Saxon 9.7, Saxon supports XPath 3.1 by default. Some features vary by Saxon edition: higher-order functions require Saxon-PE or higher, and schema-awareness requires Saxon-EE." See: http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/expressions/xpath31new.html

Answer (score 1):

In case of XSLT and Saxon-HE 9.7.0.3J, it works by using `-xsltversion:3.0` command-line option or `version="3.0"` attribute of the document element.