# Saxon: Going from XPath 2.0 to XPath 3.1

Tags: java, saxon

At present we perform XPath 2.0 queries (in Java) using:

```
// set earlier
XPathCompiler xPath;
XdmNode xmlDocument;

XPathExecutable exe = xPath.compile(query);
XPathSelector selector = exe.load();
selector.setContextItem(xmlDocument);
XdmValue nodeSet = selector.evaluate();
```

To use XPath 3.1, is it just update to Saxon 10 and the above is now XPath 3.1 ([I think it does default to 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007495/how-to-use-xpath-3-1-in-saxon))? Or do I need to call it differently?

And if differently, is there an example somewhere on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's right, just upgrade and you'll be using XPath 3.1 by default.

Saxon does have options to lower the language level (`XPathCompiler.setLanguageVersion('2.0')`) but there's very little point unless you're trying to pass conformance tests.